# onclick if else conditions

Tags: php, if-statement, onclick

Need help with onclick if else statement.

I have an `onclick=getElementById` that displays a hidden div, but need some conditions before display.

The condition variable is in a xml file -  herewith code ( I made a fiddle example but unsure how to add php code in fiddle) - https://jsfiddle.net/0thp8u38/11/

```
<?php

if (!empty($linkwebsite->nodeValue)){
    echo "<a href='$linkwebsite->nodeValue' class='button1'  target='_blank'>$ctabutton->nodeValue</a>";
}
else{
    echo "<a href='//www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=$ppy->nodeValue' class='button1'  target='_blank'>Unlock MyMobi</a>";
}
?>
```

I need to incorporate the condition as follow :-
if variable `$linkwebsite->nodeValue` is empty it must display `"Unlock Demo"` and if click must follow

```
<a href='//www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=$ppy->nodeValue'></a>
```

if variable `$linkwebsite->nodeValue` is populated it must display `$ctabutton->nodeValue` and when click must display the hidden div (`onclick=getElementById`)

I have added the php code in the fiddle but I know it is not html but just an idea what i want to achieve

Help will be highly appreciated

Comment: You can't use PHP in jsfiddle.

Comment: yes i know i just added it for clarity what i try to achieve

Comment: What do you mean by `onclick=getElementById`? Do you mean you want to  display the hidden DIV whose ID is in `href=$linkwebsite->nodeValue`?

Comment: Yes, I want to incorporate the php code condition within the
    <span style="display:block"><div class="subscribe" onclick="getElementById('hidden-div').style.display = 'block'; this.style.display = 'none'">Click Here</div></span>